# Using tinymce (and its plugins) as a commonjs module with webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, webpack

I am migrating my application from using backbone views and requirejs to  es6 (using babel) and webpack, using the commonjs modules.

I am using tinymce also. I am making tinymce into a separate bundle which is lazily loaded using `bundle-loader`. But i am using some plugins of tinymce also, and tinymce *requires* them separately. But because tinymce was loaded as a webpack chunk, the plugins arent able to initialize and im getting errors like

```
Uncaught module definition dependecy not found: tinymce/util/Tools
```

What would be the correct way to use tinymce with plugins, with webpack ?? Any leads would help.